# how to show few icons on hover of vertical icon in react grid

Tags: reactjs, button, grid, hover, action

I am using react grid ui
https://codesandbox.io/s/m6yve?file=/src/App.tsx:1102-1106

in the following when we hover on vertical icon currently it shows
[image]

it show open details rather it should show three icon
[image]

i am not getting any clue to make the change please provide some pointers on it